# How do I check if a button's class is changed in selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a test using selenium in C#. I've this IsAt method that checks if I'm at the page.

On the page, there's this button called "Button1" and if it's selected its class is changed, gets a "-seld" added at the end.
See these pictures for details:

[image: ime]

[image: ime 2]

I want to check if button1 is selected by checking its class.
First by locating it...

```
var button1selected = driver.findelement(by.ID("t_32);
```

...and then an if-statement. Except, I'm not sure how to write it.
I want to do something like this:

```
if (button1selected.class == z-tab-seld)
return true;
else
return false;
```

Any ideas? Or perhaps there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GetAttribute()` method

```
if (button1selected.GetAttribute("class").Contains("z-tab-seld"))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Or in shorter version

```
return button1selected.GetAttribute("class").Contains("z-tab-seld");
```

Comment: the class attribute contains a list of classes (z-tab and z-tab-seld). How is a simple equals() going to work then?